# STM32 ADC doesn't go faster than 10kHz

Tags: stm32, adc, dma

I'm struggling myself working on STM32F446RE (Nucleo-64).

I'm using a Bare Metal approach, so no Cube MX generated code here :) .

The microcontroller works at **16MHz**, using the HSI internal clock.
I leaved default setting for AHB, APB1, and APB2 PRE registers. So doing, timers and peripherals work either at 16MHz.

I configured the DAC to produce a sinusoid. While TIM6 triggers DAC sample generation, DMA1 manages fast memory to peripheral data transfer. It works fine, and I'm getting exactly what I expected from my calculation. Using a Look Up Table of 1000 samples, the DAC generate a sinusoid up to 1KHz.

At the same time, I'm using ADC1 and ADC2 in Dual-ADC regular synchronized mode. Basically, TIM3 triggers the conversions and DMA2 (Normal Mode) is responsible of fast data transfer from peripheral to memory. As soon as the DMA2 transfer ends, TIM3 is stopped and no conversion takes place until data are transferred through UART. This latter is set to work with 460800 Baud Rate and sends 100 samples of 2 byte for channel.

**ADC PRESCALER** is **2**, so the peripherals works at **8MHz** and a single cycle is 125ns. Also, ADCs are configured to work with **12bit resolution** and **3 sample and hold cycles**. As I'm using Dual-ADC regular and synchronized mode, the max achievable ADC sampling rate is about **533kHz** (8MHz/15).

As I need to acquire at least 100 sample per period, the sampling frequency needs to be 100 times the signal frequency. To accomplish this requirement, I'm setting the `TIM3->ARR` as follows:

`TIM3->ARR = ((uint32_t) (SYSTEM_CORE_CLOCK / ((float)(TIM3->PSC+1) * f )))-1;`

where f is the sampling frequency.

I have tested this system with 10-100-200-1000 Hz sinusoid. Consequently, the ADC sampling frequency is 1k-10k-20k-100k Hz respectively. At 1kHz and 10kHz the system works pretty well and I'm able to see on MATLAB a clear waveform of one period with 100 point.
See the following image from my oscilloscope.
[image]

The problem rises at 20kHz and above. I haven't investigated the behaviour between 10kHz and 20kHz so
I can't say which exactly is the working/not working crossover sampling frequency.

At 20kHz sampling frequency, the ADC seems to work at 10kHz. As you can see in the image, the ADC_DMA task takes about 10ms to acquire 100 sample. So I'm getting 50 point per period.
[image]

Things get worse at 100k, the ADC takes about 7ms to acquire 100 point. So I'm getting about 14 samples per period. According to the oscilloscope and MATLAB acquisition it is actually working at 14.3kHz. See the image below.
[image]

I hope someone can help me.

#### UPDATE 04/10/2023

Here are results from a deeper check.

Referring to the image below, the **yellow signal** is **toggled** every time an ADC End Of Conversion Event (EOC) occurs. The time between two consecutive toggles is clearly the sampling period. The **blue track** is a **PWM signal** with 50% duty cycle and it is generated by the TIM3. At **each falling edge** a TIM3 **Update Event** (UE) happens and a new ADC conversions should be triggered.

For a 100Hz input signal and 10kHz sampling frequency data are consistent, and the system works like a charm.

The behaviour changes for an input sinusoid of 200Hz.
[image]

In this case the sampling period(frequency) is **supposed** to be **50us**(20kHz), but it is still **100us**(10kHz).
The PWM signal has a period(frequency) of 50us(20kHz), so it's working at the frequency it is supposed to work.
Also, the distance from UE to EOC represents the conversion time. It is of about 40us which is way larger than 1,88us ((12+3)*125ns).

As soon as possible, I will test the code on a new board to rule out any problems regarding the chip.

Comment: You write that "no conversion takes place until data are transferred through UART", but you haven't told us what your UART baud rate is or what format you're using to send your samples over the UART. This stage is almost certainly the bottleneck in your system.

Comment: @brhans Thanks for the reply. You're right, I forgot the details about the UART. UART4 works with 460800 Baud Rate and sends 400 bytes in total (100 samples of two bytes per channel). I'm updating the post with missing details, but I'm pretty sure that the UART transmission is irrelevant. Analog conversion and serial transmission occur into two different tasks and never overlap in time. Also, there are no time constrains so each task takes its time.

Comment: If I understood your firmware design you sequentaly alternates between running DMA driven ADC and transmitting over UART. In such case most probably ADC conversion do not begin immediately after previous UART transmission completes as you have highlighted on picture. It needs to configure DMA and ADC peripherals which may take a long time in comparison with fast DMA driven ADC conversions. Try compile with different optimization level and see difference. UART time most probably will not change but ADC_DMA time will.

Comment: Better experiment to test ADC rate is collecting 100 samples, measuring time, then collecting 101 samples and comparing. This can compensate software overhead time.

Comment: Hi @Misaz, thanks for the comment. I have just tried different level of optimization but to no avail. I have updated the post with an additional check.